# How to avoid unnecessary Relative layout in Linear Layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout

I am using a Linear Layout to display an ImageView and to make it be displayed only one half of the screen. What I have done is to add a Relative layout inside this Linear Layout so that this ImageView only occupies one half of the screen. I am getting a warning as it is normal because this Relative Layout doen't have any children but I have used it only to occupy the other half of the screen. How could I make the same result avoiding this warning?

This is what I have:

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/img"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
```

Comment: Make the _RelativeLayout_ a _View_ instead.

Comment: Have you considered switching to a ConstraintLayout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code, imageView is only half the screen:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="2"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/img"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: One question, why are you using **xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"** ? It is working for me without using that lines of code, I have that lines of code in a parent linear layout of this linear layout. Should I put that lines of code in both linear layouts or it is okay if I put them only in the parent layout?

Comment: You just shared that part of your code, so i assumed it's your only code and added that lines. In your case delete them and have it in only parent layout.

Comment: If the Relative Layout weight was for example 1.5 instead of 1, according to your awnser, I would have to delete the Relative Layout and later assign ImageView layout_weight: 1.5 and Image View layout_height:0dp  Is that right?

Comment: The code  `android:weightSum="2"` is your total screen height. And the imageview is one child of its parent and has `android:layout_weight="1"` means its 1/2 of the screen. The other 1/2 of screen is emty, for example you can create 2 more imageview below it with each of them occupies 1/4 of screen adding `android:layout_weight="0.5"` to them. Basically you share `weightSum` to child `weight` s. You can change `weightSum` to whatever you want.